# How to call out the only even column header as x axis, while odd column act as y axis on pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

my third attempt on finding possible solutions on my coding. As reference on the worked out on my coding. I attached my previous questions.

My first questions posted :[How to make all the rows data drop the similar data and multiplying float numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68798239/how-to-make-all-the-rows-data-drop-the-similar-data-and-multiplying-float-number?noredirect=1#comment121586294_68798239)
My second questions posted :[How to pick a specific columns of header of even number only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68877971/how-to-pick-a-specific-columns-of-header-of-even-number-only/68878017#68878017)

Now, I want to plotted the graph on my data. Here which I attempt on:

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
fig,axes = plt.subplots(nrows =1,ncols =2,figsize =(15,5))
fig.subplots_adjust(hspace= 0.8)

df2.plot(ax = axes[0])
axes[0].set_title('xxx')
axes[0].set_xlabel('f',fontsize=12,color = 'r')
```

which the output is as I predicted, in a kind of jumbled out as the data produced generally. How do I set on x axis only [even columns] and y axis [odd columns]? in my graph. How should I called out in the dataframe?.Thank you in advance.

Updated (28/8/2021):

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
fig,axes = plt.subplots(nrows =1,ncols =2,figsize =(15,5))
fig.subplots_adjust(hspace= 0.8)
#df2 =df2.astype(float)
#even_cols = df2.columns[::2]
#odd_cols = df2.columns[1::2]
#df2.plot(ax = axes[0])
#df2[even_columns].plot(ax = axes[0])
#df2[odd_columns].plot(ax = axes[0])
axes[0].set_title('US')
axes[0].set_xlabel('f',fontsize=12,color = 'r')
#axes[0].set_xticklabels('f', rotation=90)
axes[0].set_xlim([0,18])
#axes[0].set_ylim([0,-100])
#ax.legend()
df2.plot(ax = axes[0],legend=False)
#plt.show()
```

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PScfV.png)
I am sorry for the late reply and trying on suggested answer for my problem. Got (-1) which I deserved for late response. Anyway, The graph that I have does not show graph that I want.

The previous one show much likely the actual graph.[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mv4VR.png)
I am sorry if my questions, confuses you guys.

Update data 30/8/2021:
[Here is the data](https://github.com/ZebraKatz/ZebraKatz/blob/ed46b807b1e08b63f56d0cedb8e299e09550d927/us_test_drop.csv)

---Update (31/8/2021)----

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.grid()
for i in range(int(len(df.keys())/2)):
    ax.plot(df[f'{df.keys()[i*2]}'], df[f'{df.keys()[i*2+1]}'])
```

I added as the suggest after that. The error shows :

```
\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2645             try:
-> 2646                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2647             except KeyError:

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\index_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.index.Int64Engine._check_type()

KeyError: '0'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-fe714e6030fb> in <module>
     19 ax.grid()
     20 for i in range(int(len(df.keys())/2)):
---> 21     ax.plot(df[f'{df.keys()[i*2]}'], df[f'{df.keys()[i*2+1]}'])

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   2798             if self.columns.nlevels > 1:
   2799                 return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
-> 2800             indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
   2801             if is_integer(indexer):
   2802                 indexer = [indexer]

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\range.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
    351             except ValueError:
    352                 raise KeyError(key)
--> 353         return super().get_loc(key, method=method, tolerance=tolerance)
    354 
    355     @Appender(_index_shared_docs["get_indexer"])

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2646                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2647             except KeyError:
-> 2648                 return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
   2649         indexer = self.get_indexer([key], method=method, tolerance=tolerance)
   2650         if indexer.ndim > 1 or indexer.size > 1:

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\index_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.index.Int64Engine._check_type()

KeyError: '0'
```

what does keyerror state `0`? I then try to adjust it. But, it keep on pointing on the `0`. I did not state column 0?

Comment: `even_columns = df.columns[::2]` and `odd_columns = df.columns[1::2]`

Comment: I thought @Henry Ecker already answer this question in your previous question that you attached above?

Comment: Henry Ecker has answer the questions on my previous question. But, I want to advance further in plotting the graph by dividing  the even columns for x-axis and odd columns for y-axis. Indicate that I just used as the command and set as my new dataframe? I am really sorry if my questions and explanation confuse you. @Karina

Comment: Much thanks @TrentonMcKinney, I appreciate much on giving hints on my question.

Comment: so is the problem solved or do you still need further helps?

Comment: I need a further help @Karina. Sorry for the late reply.

Comment: Unless you provide us with an example for your dataframe, we can't reproduce your plot. I posted an answer using some dummy array.

Comment: it's ``import matplotlib.pyplot as plt``, not ``pylab``. I don't understand your output, you clearly created a figure with 2 subplots, why am I only seeing one in your output?

Comment: could it be that your dataframe is actually named ``df2``, but you just copied my code and went to plot ``df`` as I have in my code?

Comment: I have change the `df2`  in the copy code, then i change it to `df` but it shows the same. @Karina.

Comment: refer to my edit

Comment: @Karina, now I can see the expected code that I want and the code I want does not added up with what I have in mind. As you suggest, I think I want to take a second look on my data. I appreciate very much of your help. I will update the code later on.

Answer (score 0):

This is using pandas plotting:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

plt.close()

df = pd.DataFrame()
n = 10
for i in range(4):
    df[f'col{i}'] = np.arange(n*i, n*(i+1))

fig,axes = plt.subplots(nrows =1,ncols =2,figsize =(15,5))
axes = axes.ravel()
fig.subplots_adjust(hspace= 0.8)

for i in range(int(len(df.keys())/2)):
    df.plot(ax=axes[i], x=f'col{i*2}', y=f'col{i*2+1}')
```

`df` looks like this:

```
   col0  col1  col2  col3
0     0    10    20    30
1     1    11    21    31
2     2    12    22    32
3     3    13    23    33
4     4    14    24    34
5     5    15    25    35
6     6    16    26    36
7     7    17    27    37
8     8    18    28    38
9     9    19    29    39
```

with this output:

[image]

Which I don't recommend doing. The reason is this `MatplotlibDeprecationWarning`:

`The is_first_col function was deprecated in Matplotlib 3.4 and will be removed two minor releases later. Use ax.get_subplotspec().is_first_col() instead.`

I recommend using a normal standard matplotlib plotting.

Substitute:

```py
df.plot(ax=axes[i], x=f'col{i*2}', y=f'col{i*2+1}')
```

from above code with:

```py
axes[i].plot(df[f'{df.keys()[i*2]}'], df[f'{df.keys()[i*2+1]}'])
```

Output is the same but without the warning. Feel free to ask if something is unclear.

---edit---

try this. This will definitely work:

```
url = r"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ZebraKatz/ZebraKatz/ed46b807b1e08b63f56d0cedb8e299e09550d927/us_test_drop.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(url)

df = df.drop(columns=[f'{df.keys()[0]}']) # I assume 0 1 2 3 4 5 and so on are your index, not part of actual data

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.grid()
for i in range(int(len(df.keys())/2)):
    ax.plot(df[f'{df.keys()[i*2]}'], df[f'{df.keys()[i*2+1]}'])
```

The output is:

[image]

I realize that you have some random point here and there, if I plot it with marker, the plot looks like this:

[image]

At this point I'm not sure if this is actually the output that you are trying to achieve. Your initial code has nothing to do with this, moreover, your expected output that you added in the question doesn't look like this. However, this is how your data looks like. If this is not what you are trying to achieve, then you might want to have a second look into your data.

Comment: Thank you so much @Karina for giving hints on the solution.
I want to know
 `for i in range(4):`
 `df[f'col{i}'] = np.arange(n*i, n*(i+1))`
Is to clarify the column, isn't? or am I mistaken it other way. So the way it plot the even column will be x axis, and y axis be odd.

Comment: what do you mean by _to clarify the column_? The first 4 row starting from ``df = pd.DataFrame()`` to ``df[f'col{i}'] = np.arange(n*i, n*(i+1))`` are there just _to create_ the dummy array, because you did not provide any example. Basically, if you can upload your array, I can adapt the code to match your need.

Comment: I apologize with my uncomprehend the suggestions in uploading the data.(https://github.com/ZebraKatz/ZebraKatz/blob/ed46b807b1e08b63f56d0cedb8e299e09550d927/us_test_drop.csv). I am not sure it can be read. I am so sorry for late reply.

Comment: What output do you expect? column number 0, 2, 4, 6 and so on have the exact same value from their respective row 0 till row 170. Refer to my edit

Comment: ,the expected that I have in mind is like yours. I want to see all the data plotted. Let me try it out like your suggested answer. Thank you again for helping me. I will update the image I have in mind and plotted it.